# Mostrar productos woocommerce en plantilla front-page.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy montando un sitio nuevo en WP y woocommerce, pero he montado mi sitio usando una plantilla bootstrap y troceando cada parte de esta para generar las demás plantillas, (Header, Footer, Nav...) Me gustaría que en el front page aparecieran algunos de mis productos. Como podría hacer esto¿??

Por cierto, tengo que decir que no he elegido plantilla en las opciones de lectura. Yo he creado mi tema y desde apariencia lo he elegido.

Un saludo y agradezco toda ayuda

He hecho esto en mi front-page.php de mi tema, pero no me aparecen los productos:

```
<div class="contenedor-productos">
   <?php do_shortcode('[product_category category="Vespa"]'); ?>
</div>
```

y en **functions.php** le he dado soporte de la siguiente manera.

```
/* SOPORTE PARA woocommerce */

function woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'centermoto' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );

/* AGREGAR SOPORTE PARA SHORTCODE */

add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Como podría hacerlo¿??

tengo que decir que soy desarrollador web pero estoy empezando con todo lo relacionado con WP y algunas cosas las tengo muy verdes.

Un salduo y gracias por todo de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo facilmente con wp_query.

```
<ul class="products">
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda,

Un saludo